# How can I create an offline validation system for a Xamarin app?

Tags: validation, xamarin, uwp, offline

I have created an Xamarin App that will work on totally offline.

I would like to implement some mechanism that validates the application with a Key/Password.

I have something in mind like, the following:

1. From the app with a button, generate a kind of random key.
2. From another application, enter the previous key and generate the final key.
3. Finally enter the newly generated password in the app.

Is it possible to do something similar? is there any methodology to do it?

Anyone who wants a hint or help would be well appreciated.

Comment: Why?  If it works totally offline what do you need this for?  If the user want to protect their own data, just have them create a password or pin they have to enter when accessing the app.

Comment: The reason is that I wanted to control the number of installations.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly work entirely offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you requirement, you could make 32-bit random character generator, and copy this 32-bit random character to another app to MD5 encrypt. Then use the MD5 result to validate.

**Main APP**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyLabel.Text = CDKMaker();
        Clipboard.SetTextAsync(KeyLabel.Text);
    }
    public string CDKMaker()
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Substring(0);
        var value = EncryptString(key);
        Preferences.Set("my_key", value);
        return key;
    }
    private string EncryptString(string str)
    {
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

        byte[] byteOld = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        byte[] byteNew = md5.ComputeHash(byteOld);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in byteNew)
        {

            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PWLabel.Text == Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value"))
        {
            // login successfully
        }
        else
        {
            //login faild 
        }
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,44,0,0">
    <Label x:Name="KeyLabel" Text="This original Key"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Button Text="Make 32 Bit Random" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Entry x:Name="PWLabel"  Placeholder="Please input password" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Button Text="Login" Clicked="Login"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Another APP**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Main app has insert the cdk into clipboard. please press ctrl + v pasted.
    var Password = EncryptString(cdk);
  
}
public static string EncryptString(string str)
{
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

    byte[] byteOld = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] byteNew = md5.ComputeHash(byteOld);
   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in byteNew)
    {
        
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }
   
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Nico, it was exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help.